# Create a raster map from more than one shape

Tags: arcgis-10.0, cartography, raster-conversion

I've some shapefile loaded in Arcmap (steets, buildings...) with an appropriate symbology ad I need to convert them to unique raster, to obtain a map (like topographic map) with a specified resolution (cellsize) ad scale.

There's a method, or plugin or program to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- Add all your data and symbology to the map
- Set data frame properties to the desired Reference scale (this way. line weights, labels and annotations will be consistent with scale)
- Once you are happy with the map Export Data view (NOT LAYOUT) to tiff(or jpeg,etc) but check on the **Write World File** check box (the option is not available when exporting from layout)

this way the image you export will have cartographic features consistent with the scale you set and will also be georeferenced.

Comment: Good point for the georeferencing

Comment: I know "export map" function but does not consider that with large map I can: A. maintain detailed scale (eg 1:2000) but saving only the geometry displayed on the screen and not the other; or 
B. view the entire work area, but losing the scale and relative detail.

What I seek is a function similar to the "Feature to Raster" (but working with more shape at once) where rasterization retains the shape of the actual size of the source file by exporting them to a georeferenced raster.

Comment: A: You maintain fetatures relative to scale by setting the reference scale in Data Frame Properties. (scale only has meaning when printed or viewed at correct paper/layout sizes) B: You can gain detail by increasing the resolution of the export file. Because the exported image will be georeferenced, you can add it to map and export to a raster at your desired "exact" resolution

Answer (score 1):

You should export your map as an image, e.g. tiff, jpeg or png, via File menu > Export Map. You can decide more or less the resolution by adjusting the dpi parameter and the scale of the map as it is at the time you export it. Then you must [georeference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000mq000000) the image in ArcMap and assign it the coordinate system of your shapefile data, so it becomes geographic data.
If you have the Production Mapping extension, there is a convenient functionality called 
[Export to Layout GeoTIFF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0106000002tt000000) that allows you to export your map layout to GeoTIFF, so no need to georeference the image.